# Diebold - Mariano test for volatility forecasts problem

Tags: forecasting, garch, volatility-forecasting, diebold-mariano-test

I am using packages {rugarch} for forecasting and {forecast} for Diebold - Mariano test. As a first step, I am specifying the first AR-GARCH model for financial time series (AAPL Nasdaq) using `ugarchspec{rugarch}`

```
   spec1 <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model =
    list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1), submodel = NULL, external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE),
  mean.model =
    list(armaOrder = c(2, 0), external.regressors = NULL), distribution.model = "norm" )
```

Then I fit it using `ugarchfit{rugarch}`

```
modelfit1=ugarchfit(spec1, data=AAPL_returns, out.sample = 200)
modelfit1
```

Then I forecast it using `ugarchforecast{rugarch}`

```
modelfor1=ugarchforecast(modelfit1, n.ahead = 1, n.roll
                        = 200, out.sample = 200)
```

This is my first forecast to be compared in Diebold-Mariano test. The other forecast is very similar to the first one but the AR-GARCH model is enhanced by the external regressor, which is data (GGL) from Google Trends on "AAPL" keyword:

```
spec2 <- ugarchspec(
      variance.model =
        list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1), submodel = NULL, external.regressors = GGL, variance.targeting = FALSE),
      mean.model =
        list(armaOrder = c(2, 0), external.regressors = NULL), distribution.model = "norm" )
```

Then I fit it:

```
modelfit2=ugarchfit(spec2, data=AAPL_returns, out.sample = 200)
modelfit2
```

And I forecast it:

```
modelfor2=ugarchforecast(modelfit2, n.ahead = 1, n.roll
                        = 200, out.sample = 200)
```

So I am ending up with two formal class uGARCHforecasts - `modelfor1, modelfor2`

Now comes the problematic part. As Diebold-Mariano `dm.test{forecast}` is working with forecasting errors, I need to save them from my previous forecast which I have done this way:

```
e1 <-(modelfor1@model$modeldata$residuals)
e2 <-(modelfor2@model$modeldata$residuals)

accuracy(e1)
accuracy(e2)
dm.test(e1,e2,h=1)
```

The `dm.test` runs without problem, however the `accuracy(e1)` is unable to provide information on summary measures of the forecast accuracy, since it returns

```
Error in accuracy(e1) : Unable to compute forecast accuracy measures
```

I would like to raise two questions:

1) Is this model as a whole well specified, does it capture a legit comparison of two well specified forecast?

2) What is the problem with inability to return accuracy measures in `accuracy(e1)` ?

**Edit:**

I suggest a second model which works with squared residuals as a proxy to forecast in-sample volatility:

```
modelsigma1 = as.data.frame(modelfit1@fit$sigma)
modelsigma2 = as.data.frame(modelfit2@fit$sigma)
ret.sq = AAPL_returns^2
modelsigma1.sq = modelsigma1^2
modelsigma2.sq = modelsigma2^2
dm.test((ret.sq - modelsigma1.sq), (ret.sq - modelsigma2.sq), alternative = c("two.sided"), h = 1, power = 1)
```

Comment: Regarding the failure of `accuracy`, type in `accuracy` and press "Enter". You will see the source code. Based on that you can manually check which `if` clause fails (there are a few of them) for your particular forecast, and then you can think of how to repair that.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

These

```
e1 <-(modelfor1@model$modeldata$residuals)
e2 <-(modelfor2@model$modeldata$residuals)
```

are not forecast errors. They are in-sample residuals from the conditional mean model.

First, in-sample residuals are not the same as out-of-sample forecast errors.
Second, you care about forecasts of *conditional variance*, not point forecasts. So even if you had out-of-sample forecast errors of the conditional mean model (the difference between point forecasts and actual realizations), that would not be what you need.

You could get an estimate of realized *unconditional* variance using high-frequency data, but I don't think you could get it from the data you used for fitting the GARCH model (except perhaps when taking on extra assumptions). I am not sure how to get realized values of *conditional* variance.

Comment: Thanks Richard. You are right that volatility is unobservable so it is unclear what we use as observed values. I then suggest to use some kind of proxy. Squared returns are not very accurate but should be satisfactory. The code is then:
  
 `modelsigma1 = as.data.frame(modelfit1@fit$sigma)
modelsigma2 = as.data.frame(modelfit2@fit$sigma)
ret.sq = AAPL_returns^2
modelsigma1.sq = modelsigma1^2
modelsigma2.sq = modelsigma2^2
dm.test((ret.sq - modelsigma1.sq), (ret.sq - modelsigma2.sq), alternative = c("two.sided"), h = 1, power = 1)`

Comment: That is better, except that squared returns are a terribly noisy proxy.